# Pressing T+R+O keys at the same time triggers an F7 key press

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, function-keys

I was trying to launch an electron project and noticed that in CMD, a dialog box kept appearing while I was typing `electron`, the weird thing is, it only happened when I typed that word.

After further investigation, I noticed it was the combination of the <kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>O</kbd> key, when pressed while not releasing the previous keys in that order, the system would trigger an <kbd>F7</kbd> call (as though <kbd>F7</kbd> were pressed). And now that I know about the issue, it seems to creep up everywhere, like in FireFox, when I type `stroke`, `trousers` or `trombone`. I get dialogs asking whether I want to activate "Caret Browsing". How do I stop this behaviour?

I have a very new Dell Inspiron 7570 running Win 10 1803. And I doubt this is caused by malware too. If anyone has any info, please help, it's getting on my nerve.

Comment: You might test with an external keyboard. This is not common behavior, and if your PC is quite new, you might exchange it for another.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, my keyboard does double press a key occasionally

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a keyboard ghosting A.K.A [key rollover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)) issue. It happens because most keyboards uses a matrix to read the pressed keys and you can't press more than N keys without issue. You can't do anything to fix it apart from buying a more expensive keyboard with N-key rollover support

- [What Is Keyboard Ghosting and Why Should You Care?](https://www.maketecheasier.com/what-is-keyboard-ghosting/)
- [What Is N-Key Rollover? A Basic Definition](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/-n-key-rollover-nkro-definition,5751.html)
- [Rollover, blocking and ghosting](https://deskthority.net/wiki/Rollover,_blocking_and_ghosting)
- [What is "anti ghosting" for a keyboard?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-anti-ghosting-for-a-keyboard)
- [What Is Keyboard Ghosting and Why You Should Care](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWuqWhw8E4Q)