# Typing by pressing three keys on keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard, typing

I've been experimenting with verious typing techniques and I've just noticed that when I press three keys simultaneously then nothing happens. By simultaneously I really mean in quick succession but for a moment all three are impressed.

Example: the word *define* =def+in+e. *def* can be accomplished by pressing the three keys *d*+*e*+*f* with the finger taking *d* positioned lower than *e* and *e* lower than *f* so you have the right *def* order, the letters are close so you only use one hand and it looks a little like the way a stenographer types. It'd effortless and takes a fraction of a second.

I know the keyboard I use is capable of sending the signals, I used an oscilloscope and the keyboard doesn't care how many keys are pressed in. A signal is sent for every key pressed and seperate signals for when a key is released.

I use Windows, tried Mozilla web browser, Ms Word, Notepad and they all fail to process triple keys. Why is this limitation imposed?

Comment: Is your keyboard PS/2 or USB? If it is USB it might be hardware limited to a maximun number of simultanueous keys. You might want to shop for a keyboard with [n-key rollover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key))

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Why can my keyboard only digest 6 keypresses at a time?](https://superuser.com/q/1445219/241386), [Pressing T+R+O keys at the same time triggers an F7 key press](https://superuser.com/a/1633386/241386)